# Push element to dynamic array (created with instance_variable_set) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a list of attributes. Each attribute will be setted as an empty array and i want to push elements to each array.

I figured out how to create a dynamic array with `instance_variable_set` but i couldn't push elements to it.

That's what i did:

```
attributes = ["eye","hair_color","hair_size","hair_type"]
i = 0
attributes.each do |a|
    # Dynamic arrays are created, like: @eye = []
    instance_variable_set("@#{a}", [])
    # My attempt to push element
    "@#{a}".push(i)
    i += 1
end
```

How can i push an element to those dynamic arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instance_variable_get("@#{a}").push(i)` will work

Answer (score 1):

Petr Balaban has it right. I thought I would also note that you can do `each_with_index` instead of setting and incrementing `i` manually:

```
attributes = ["eye","hair_color","hair_size","hair_type"]

attributes.each_with_index do |a,i|
  # Dynamic arrays are created, like: @eye = []
  instance_variable_set("@#{a}", [])
  # As Petr noted...
  instance_variable_get("@#{a}").push(i)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be:

```
attributes = %w|eye hair_color hair_size hair_type|
attributes.each_with_index do |a, idx|
  self.class.send :attr_accessor, a.to_sym
  public_send "#{a}=", idx
  (public_send a) << idx
end
```

Now you have an access to these variables by getter:

```
hair_size
#⇒ 2
```